# How can I sort a list that inside a map in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, comparable

I have a class that I created to store the results of a race, such as name and time of each driver, and I have determined that I wish the results to be compared based on the time.

```
public class Vysledek implements Comparable<Vysledek>{
private String jmeno;
private int hodina;
private int minuta;
private int sekunda;
    
public Vysledek(String jmeno, int h, int m, int s){
    if(jmeno==null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Zadejte jméno prosím");
    this.setJmeno(jmeno);
    if(h==0||m==0||s==0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Zadejte čas prosím");
    this.setCas(h, m, s);
}

public String getJmeno(){
    return jmeno;
}

public void setJmeno(String jmeno){
    this.jmeno = jmeno;
}

public void setCas(int h, int m, int s){
    this.hodina=h;
    this.minuta=m;
    this.sekunda=s;
}

public void getVysledek(){
    System.out.println(this.toString());
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Vysledek v){
    if(this.hodina<v.hodina && this.minuta<v.minuta && this.sekunda<v.sekunda)
        return -1;
    else if(this.hodina==v.hodina && this.minuta==v.minuta && this.sekunda==v.sekunda)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return this.getJmeno()+", "+hodina+":"+minuta+"."+sekunda;
}
}
```

Then I have a class to create a list and store the results there.

```
public class SerazenySeznam<Vysledek extends Comparable<Vysledek>>{
    private java.util.List<Vysledek> vysledek = new java.util.ArrayList();
    
public void add(Vysledek v){
    if(v==null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Vložte platný prvek");
    vysledek.add(v);
}

public void sort(){
    java.util.Collections.sort(vysledek);
    System.out.println(vysledek);
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return vysledek.toString();
}
}
```

In the main class I have created a map, then I put the results inside the map and I wish to sort the results based on the time. As you can see, I created a method sort() in the class to create the least, but it does not sort anything.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        java.util.Map<SerazenySeznam, Integer> mapa=new java.util.HashMap();
        
        SerazenySeznam<Vysledek> Monaco= new SerazenySeznam();
        
        Monaco.add(new Vysledek("Alain Prost",1,20,557));
        Monaco.add(new Vysledek("Michael Schmacher",1,21,190));
        Monaco.add(new Vysledek("Ayrton Senna",1,21,552));
        Monaco.add(new Vysledek("Érik Comas",1,23,246));
        Monaco.add(new Vysledek("Michael Andretti",1,22,994));
        Monaco.add(new Vysledek("Karl Wendlinger",1,22,477));
        Monaco.add(new Vysledek("Gerhard Berger",1,22,394));
        Monaco.add(new Vysledek("Riccardo Patrese",1,22,117));
        Monaco.add(new Vysledek("Jean Alesi",1,21,948));
        Monaco.add(new Vysledek("Damon Hill",1,21,825));
        
        Monaco.sort();
        
        mapa.put(Monaco, 1993);
        
        for(SerazenySeznam s : mapa.keySet())
            System.out.println(s);
    }
```

Could you tell me please how can I sort those results based on their time in the race? I hope I have been clear, but if there is something unclear, tell me and I can improve my question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider using java.time.Duration rather than tracking hours, minutes, and seconds with separate variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this in your `Vysledek` class

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Vysledek v){
    if(this.hodina<v.hodina && this.minuta<v.minuta && this.sekunda<v.sekunda)
        return -1;
    else if(this.hodina==v.hodina && this.minuta==v.minuta && this.sekunda==v.sekunda)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}
```

with this

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Vysledek v) {
        return Integer.compare(this.sekunda + this.minuta*60000 + this.hodina*60000*60, v.sekunda + v.minuta*60000 + v.hodina*60000*60);
}
```

or you can even sort it in `sort()` method in your `SerazenySeznam` class without implementing `Comparable` in `Vysledek` class. But you need to make `hodina, minuta, sekunda` properties public or make getters.

```
public void sort(){
    vysledek.sort(new Comparator<Vysledek>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Vysledek v1, Vysledek v2) {
            return Integer.compare(v1.sekunda + v1.minuta*60000 + v1.hodina*60000*60, v2.sekunda + v2.minuta*60000 + v2.hodina*60000*60);
        }
    });
}
```

PS: According to your test data, the `sekunda` property schould be named `milisekunda`, this answer treats it as milliseconds. If you want to treat it as seconds, replace previous with this:

```
Integer.compare(this.sekunda + this.minuta*60 + this.hodina*3600, v.sekunda + v.minuta*60+ v.hodina*3600);
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not a good idea to compare hours with hours, minutes with minutes and second with seconds to find which HH:MM:SS combination is the fastest. There can be cases like 04:50:56 < 05:00:00, which does not evaluate well in your original `compareTo()` method.

Try this code instead:

```
public int compareTo(Vysledek v){
    Integer counterSekundaThis = this.sekunda + this.minuta*60 +this.hodina*3600;
    Integer counterSekundaV = v.sekunda + v.minuta*60 + v.hodina*3600;

    return counterSekundaThis.compareTo(counterSekundaV);
}
```

Comment: upvote, a little thing to add is if-else conditions can be replaced by        
```return counterSekundaThis.compareTo(counterSekundaV);```
Because objects should be compared using equals method

Comment: Yes, that is a very nice replacement. Thank you @ZhuragatBolatkhan

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend that instead of storing it in your class

```
private int hodina;
private int minuta;
private int sekunda;
```

You use `LocalTime` for this purpose as it's Java's API to manage times. You can create an instance of it using `LocalTime.of(hodina, minuta, sekunda)`. `LocalTime` already implements a `compareTo` to sort by time.

Your class could look something like this:

```
private static class Vysledek implements Comparable<Vysledek> {
    private String jmeno;
    private LocalTime time;

    public Vysledek(String jmeno, int h, int m, int s) {
      if (jmeno == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Zadejte jméno prosím");
      }
      this.setJmeno(jmeno);
      time = LocalTime.of(h, m, s);
    }

    .
    .
    .
   
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Vysledek v) {
      return this.time.compareTo(v.time);
    }
  }
```

Comment: I posted the same solution then saw you posted in an hour earlier :) +1